# About training data for spaCy NER

Tags: nlp, spacy, training-data

I'm new to NLP.
Now I'm trying to create NER model for extracting music artist's name from some text.
But It hasn't gone well.This is what I've done.

1. I got 1500,000 artist's name list.
2. I created training data with string template.like this "{artist's name} is so sick."
   All 1500,000 training data is like this string.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Nirvana is so sick", {"entities": [(0, 7, "ARTIST")]}),
    ("City girls is so sick", {"entities": [(0, 10, "ARTIST")]}),
    ("Taylor swift is so sick", {"entities": [(0, 12, "ARTIST")]}),
]
```

(Maybe this is the reason it doesn't go well?)

3. I used the model after training 30,000 datas.
4. But I didn't work at all.All sentence was extracted as ARTIST.
   Below is example. 'Chris Thomas King' is artist's name in this case.

```
Entities [('Not sure how they handled it during filming, but Tim Blake Nelson did sing his own parts (as did Chris Thomas King).', 'ARTIST')]
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a finite number of artist names? or are you looking to generalize?

Comment: To generalize is better.But It looks so diffcult.
My plan is it let model learn finite artist(1.5M).
Then it gradually let model learn few additional names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this problem differently. The way you are generating training data is biased in my opinion. Below are the steps I would follow to generate the training data.

To generate the training data:

1. Start with the list of artist names that you have and initialize a PhraseMatcher. See [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher) for details on how to do this.
2. Then, use the matcher to tag the names of artists in your sentences (30k sentences that you have)
3. The sentences that you found matches on, select say 2k of them. Each match will have start and end index of the match. Use this to generate the training data i.e. TRAIN_DATA

Once, this is done, you can train your model using the training data.

**EDIT**

1. You have 1.5 million artist names
2. Next, you need now think of, "what context do I want my model to detect these names in?"
3. Once you have an answer to 2, it is time to generate training data. You should train your model in similar contexts in which you would want them to detect names. For example:

   - If you want your model to detect artist names in news headlines, you should collect 1k to 2k new headlines which have artist names in them.
   - If you want you model to detect names in reddit comments, you should get 1k to 2k reddit comments which have the artist names in them.
   - How do you know if these have artist names you ask? You have the 1.5M artist names, you can do dictionary lookup to verify.
4. Now that you have your context set, and good amount of training data set, it is time to "annotate" the data.
5. There are many ways to annotate

   1. Manually annotate using an annotation software, Doccano, Prodigy, and many more
   2. Use PhraseMatcher to match detect the names of artists just like you did in (3).
6. Now you have your annotated data; time to train the model.
7. Voila, you are done and now have a generalized model in hand.
8. Still unhappy with the results?

   - Add more training data, go to (3), repeat

Comment: Thank you for commenting!
That sounds so nice!

But Do you expect I have 30k sample sentences that include artist name like this?

```
・I like Taylor swift so Much
・City girls just release their new songs!
・Nirvana is one of the greatest band in rock history.
etc...30k sentences
```

Unfortunately,I don't have them.
I only have just 1.5M artist name list.

I think I've understood about spaCy Matcher.
Do you think I still should use this approach?

Comment: Do you expect I have 30k sample sentences that include artist name like this? 
No. I do not expect you to have 30k sentences. You need about 1k to 2k sentences with artist names in them. Then you can use the matcher to detect the artist names in those sentences. You need to keep in mind that the 1.5M artist names should have the names of the artists you are looking to detect in the 1k-2k sentences that you are "annotating"

Comment: I added a more in depth explanation in my original post under EDIT.

Comment: It looks so nice.Thank you for writing!  
You mean I need to collect only 1k-2k sample data?  
My question is If I make model learn 1k-2k datas,is it possible that model extract 1.5M artist name?

Comment: Yes. It is possible, but I cannot give you an answer for sure. You have to test. You have to understand that the model doesnt know all the names, it is trying to generalize. So you might have to train with more data if the generalization isnt good.

Comment: I see.I'll try to get 1k-2k real sentences.then training and test them.Thank you for your great advice!

Answer (score 0):

If all your training data is just the same sentence but with different artist name e.g. "[artist] is so sick", you need more variety in your training data.

For example, "This song is by [artist]", "[artist] won an Emmy for this song", "Is this the best song by [artist] ever?". Generating training data by replacing just the artist name in one sentence will not work.

What you need is not a lot of artist names but a lot of different sentences with different words.

Comment: Thank you for telling that!

> you need more variety in your training data.

I think this is point.I'll try to create training data with many variety templates.

> What you need is not a lot of artist names but a lot of different sentences with different words.

You mean it's possible even if model doesn't learn specific name(Let's say "Taylor swift")
model learn a lot of different sentences without the word "Taylor swift"
then model can extract "Taylor swift"?

Comment: You mean it's possible even if model doesn't learn specific name(Let's say "Taylor swift") model learn a lot of different sentences without the word "Taylor swift" then model can extract "Taylor swift"? -<<<< Yes, that's the point of machine learning so that you teach it general pattern rather than all possible examples.

Comment: That's awesome...! I was thinking NER need to make model learn specific name(ex.Taylor Swift). If I don't do that,model never extract the name. I see.Thank you for telling that!